Python tkinter gif too fast, large and oly shows small portion of center of image
When I try to run the code, the gif displays at a very high speed and only shows the center of the gif. The window size is also much too large once the start button is pressed.
I tried to run this code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Displaying Gif")

#idle animation stuff
Idle = "C:\\Users\\Andy\\Downloads\\desktoppetstuff\\DesktopPetTvIdle.gif"
IdleInfo = Image.open(Idle)

IdleFrames = IdleInfo.n_frames #num of frames
    
IdleGifObjects = []
for i in range(IdleFrames):
    obj = tk.PhotoImage(file=Idle, format=f"gif -index {i}")
    IdleGifObjects.append(obj)
    
    #make anim work
def IdleAnim(CurrentFrame=0):
    global loop
    image = IdleGifObjects [CurrentFrame]
    
    IdleGifLabel.configure(image=image)
    CurrentFrame = CurrentFrame + 1
    
    if CurrentFrame == IdleFrames:
        CurrentFrame = 0
    
    loop = root.after(50, lambda: IdleAnim(CurrentFrame))

def StopAnim():
    root.after_cancel(loop)
    
IdleGifLabel = Label(root, image="")
IdleGifLabel.pack()

start = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda: IdleAnim(CurrentFrame=0))
start.pack()

stop = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=StopAnim)
stop.pack()

root.mainloop()


The speed of the animation can be controlled by the 50 in the .after. As for the size of the image, you will have to look at how to show PIL images and resize them using PIL (tkinter built-in resizing isn't very good)

You are only waiting 50 milliseconds between each frame. Change the value to 500 (half a second), or any other larger value.

Can you post the GIF image and a screen shot of the output of your code?  The size of the window should be around the size of the GIF image after the GIF frames are being shown.

Suggest to use Pillow.Image class to load the frames of the GIF image.  It is much faster than using tk.PhotoImage(..., format="...").
